# How to Script a Unity Material to "Materialize"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a script that makes a material "erode" or dissolve. But I want to make it do the exact opposite so it can "materialize" but I don't understand how to calculate it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Erode : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float erodeRate = 0.03f;
    public float erodeRefreshRate = 0.01f;
    public float erodeDelay = 1f;
    public Material materialSlot1;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Material1());
    }

    IEnumerator Material1()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(erodeDelay);

        float t = 0;
        while (t < 1)
        {
            t += erodeRate;
            materialSlot1.SetFloat("_Erode", t);
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(erodeRefreshRate);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to already have something that fulfills the opposite. So simply invert the value:

```
materialSlot1.SetFloat("_Erode", 1 - t);
```

now the factor goes from `1` to `0` while time passes.

---

In general instead of going in step increments it might be cooler to have this as a smooth effect and rather do e.g.

```
public float durationInSeconds = 1f;

IEnumerator Start()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(erodeDelay);

    for(var timePassed = 0f; timePassed < durationInSeconds; timePassed += Time.deltaTime)
    {
        var factor = 1 - timePassed / durationInSeconds;
        materialSlot1.SetFloat("_Erode", factor);
        yield return null;
    }

    materialSlot1.SetFloat("_Erode", 0);
}
```